# Is this possible to write 2 condition in single while controller?

Tags: jmeter

if possible ,please post sample logic. one condition should follow your logic ,that 2 condition should check some text.
example :-
${__groovy("${textcheck1}".indexOf("Message") == -1 && ("${textcheck2}".indexOf("Message1") == -1,))}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy String provides [`contains()` function](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) so it worth considering re-writing your code to use `contains` instead of `indexOf`, it will be more readable.

With regards to "posting sample logic" we don't know what you're trying to achieve with these conditions, see [Logical Operators](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_logical_operators) user manual chapter for more information.

You can also check [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) article for some useful Groovy hints related to JMeter